# Error resetting database index using ALTER TABLE in $wpdb->query

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb, wp-cron

I'm running a Cron job every hour that clears all posts of a particular CPT and then re-inserts data by accessing a third party API.

I'm worried that this will lead to huge indexes, so I would like to reset the wp_post and wp_postmeta indexes after this happens.

I've used the following PHP code...

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
```

but I get the error

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta AUTO_INCREMENT = 1' at line 2 for query ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; made by do_action_ref_array('job_cron'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, job_run_cron
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many posts are you inserting? The post ID column will work fine with numbers all the way up to `18446744073709551615`. That's over 18 quintillion. Do you really expect to get anywhere close to this? Keep in mind that a 18 quintillion only takes 8 bytes to store, which is the equivalent of 8 letters. In terms of memory/performance it's going to be dwarfed by your actual content. This really sounds like textboox premature optimisation.

Comment: this is not a good idea, you can avoid the issue by not doing this. If what you're doing did reset the indexes, your server would experience a slowdown deleting them, then another slowdown recreating them, coupled with reduced performance during re-indexing, so you get a performance hit, and the index would be just as large afterwards anyway